# Angular2 google authentication, TypeError on button rendering

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, google-authentication

Long story short: I'm trying to write google authentication using Angular2 (Typescript).

When I'm trying to render a button im getting weird result.

For code:

```
    gapi.signin2.render("google-login-btn",
        {
            "onSuccess": (user) => console.log(user),
            "scope": "profile email",
            "theme": "dark"
        }
    )
```

I'm getting error:

```
TypeError: task is null
patchTimer/clearNative</<()
clearTimeout()
db/t()
db/F[G]/b()
db/F[G]()
db/C[pa]()
<anonymous>
```

In my template I have:

```
    <div class="login-wrapper" style="background-color: white;">
        <p>You need to log in.</p>
        <div id="google-login-btn"></div>
    </div>
```

and in code the method that invokes this is:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(gapi);
    gapi.signin2.render(
        "google-login-btn",
        {
            "onSuccess": (user) => console.log(user),
            "scope": "profile email",
            "theme": "dark"
        }
    );
}
```

In my index.html somewhere of course is:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

source is here

http://pastebin.com/qTKTFaXf

http://pastebin.com/AWyDX8qW

http://pastebin.com/x5ryD6ju

Comment: Is this about Angular.js or Angular2?

Comment: Where does your error originate from? Can you post the entire class using that template? Can you remove the `async` and `defer` from the script tag?

Comment: it's angular 2 (which is kinda obvious - title), with removed async and defer nothing changes.

Comment: added source to post

Comment: Then you shouldn't add the `angularjs` tag (I removed it already).

Comment: Well, I thought that the problem may be specific to this kinds of framework and not necessarily fault of wrong usage of framework but more about not getting the wider concept, but if that is against the rules then nvm

Comment: @user3212350 Where do you receive the error?

Comment: Where? Well, the method ngAfterViewInit() is called after the view is initialized, in this moment I get an error in browser console. I can duplicate it with just typing into console the code which is first in my question.

Comment: how do you were able to solve your issue? I am facing a similar problem..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `google-login-btn` as `id` in your html element, but you try to initialise it with the `id` `google-login-button`.. I suspect your problem lies there. Although, in the 3rd code snippet you do use `google-login-button`.. mmmm. Well, check it anyways!

Comment: no, it's btn everywhere, just a typo when i was pasting and changed that